# How should I solve $u_t=u_{xx}+4u+x^2-2t-4x^2t+2 \cos^2(x)$ if one of its conditions is $u_x(\pi ,t)=2\pi t$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    u_t=u_{xx}+4u+x^2-2t-4x^2t+2\cos^2(x),  x\in (0,\pi) \\
    u(x,0)=0 \\
    u_x(0,t)=0 \\
    u_x(\pi ,t)=2\pi t 
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I tried to use $u(x,t)=v(x)+w(x,t)$ somehow, but even if I do something like $v_{xx}(x)+4v=-x^2-2\cdot \cos^2(x)$ and $w_t(x,t)=-2t-4x^2t$ dla $w_{xx}(x,t)=0$ I end up with "not the right conditions", this means I'm just left with

\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    v_{xx}(x)=-4v-x^2-2\cdot \cos^2(x)\\
    v_x(0)=0 \\
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

If I'd have $u_x(\pi,t)=2\pi $ instead of $u_x(\pi,t)=2\pi t$, I would have a differential equations with two conditions, it'd be fine.

But right now, it isn't. So how should I solve that PDE? Should I use $u(x,t)=v(x,t)+w(x,t)$?